# How do I run a Bash script on files within folders and keep folder name?

Tags: bash

I have a cloned git repo that I'm working with. In each folder is a file called config.js. I have a script that SHOULD convert each file in the repo, ending in .js, to a csv and rename it to foldername.config.js.csv. What Bash loop should I use to accomplish this? Forgive me, for I don't really know Bash at all, but from what I was able to figure out I did:

```
for NAME in `find . -iname 'config.js'`; do 
        DIRNAME=`echo $NAME | cut -d \/ -f 3` 
        ./do_conversion_script.sh $NAME
        mv config.js.csv $DIRNAME.config.js.csv
done
```

This successfully applied the script to all the files but it only converted the file and added .csv to the end of it. So instead of giving me foldername.config.js.csv, it just gave me config.js.csv. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `DIRNAME=...` can you give an example? Suppose I found `config.js` file at `./A/B/C/config.js`. What should I rename it to?

Comment: Wrap `DIRNAME` with `{}` and quote, like so: `mv config.js.csv "${DIRNAME}.config.js.csv"`

Comment: @Perplexabot This wouldn't fix any problem as `DIRNAME` is derived from ``in `find …`; do`` which already splits at (and therefore removes) spaces. The `{}` are optional here too – there is no advantage of using them.

Comment: @Socowi , the `{}` are there to separate the variable from the rest of the string, as bash would not know when the variable's name starts and ends (he got lucky due to having a `.` right after). The quotes are recommended in general when trying to access bash vars. It may not fix his issue but it definitely will make for more stable code (hence why this is a comment).

Comment: @Perplexabot Sorry for being mean. As we all know, your suggestions are good in *general*. I just read them as *"this will solve the problem"* instead of *"general recommendation: …"*.

Comment: @Socowi , I see what you mean. No worries : ) Thank you for the feedback. I should have preceded my original comment with a "In general ...".

Comment: don't you want `$DIRNAME/config.js.csv` ? (note the `/` char). Good luck.

Comment: Semantics, but you can also use `while read -r NAME; do ... done < <(find . -iname 'config.js')` Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first let me make some assumptions:

- Your directory tree looks like:
  `./dir/a/config.js`
  `./dir/b/config.js`
  etc.
- The `do_conversion_script.sh` creates the `config.js.csv` file in the
  same directory as `config.js`.
- You want to prepend a suffix to the `config.js.csv` file with
  its parent name as `a` or `b` in case of the example above.
- The renamed file is located in the same directory as before.
- The parent names do not duplicate.
- The pathnames do not include any of whitespace, tab and newline.

Then how about:

```
for name in $(find . -iname 'config.js'); do
    dir="${name%/*}"
    prefix="${dir##*/}"
    ./do_conversion_script.sh "$name"
    mv -- "$dir/config.js.csv" "$dir/$prefix.config.js.csv"
done
```

You may need to use two variables which holds the full directory name from the current directory and the one which holds just the parent name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To handle `"$name"` without a path, you should include `[ "$dir" = "$name" ] && dir='.'` after `dir="${name%/*}"` otherwise the `mv` will fail. (yes, outside of your assumptions, but still good to mention)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for your suggestion. If the file exists in the current directory
(I suppose this is the case you mention with `"$name" without a path`),
the filename is prefixed by `./` as a result of `find`.
Then `mv` will not fail but the created filename is `..config.js.csv`,
a hidden file :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I dunno if I better to handle with this special case. I'd be happy if I hear your frank opinion.

Comment: You are correct, the default filename returned by `find` will be prefixed with `./` so you are safe in this case. The note is a general note about using the *parameter expansion with substring removal* to remove the filename leaving the path. The additional check handles the case where the filename alone is given similar to what the `dirname` command would do. (the answer was good so you got my UV)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I appreciate your prompt and kind instruction. It helped me a lot!. Your suggestion will be my future reference. BR.

Comment: I really wonder when will you guys stop looping over find's output. It's an antipattern

Comment: @oguzismail thank you for the comment. Certainly I've known that and do 100% agree with the opinion. But this time I've traced OP's structure just to focus on the correction in the directory names. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of calculating DIRNAME does not make sense. Say if I have

```
NAME=a/b/c
echo $NAME | cut -d \/ -f 3
```

this produces `c`, not `a/b`.

You could use

```
DIRNAME=$(dirname $NAME)
```

or

```
DIRNAME=${NAME%/*}
```

instead. The former is better readable, the latter saves ones child process.